# What is the best possible implementation for the following recursively query?

Tags: sql

I got a table with the following struct representing a file system.
Every item, might be a file or a folder, has a unique id. If it is a category(folder), it contains other files.
`level` indicates the directory depth.

```
|id |parent_id|is_category|level|
|:-:|:   -   :|:    -    :|: - :|
|0  |   -1    |    true   |  0  |
|1  |    0    |    true   |  1  |
|2  |    0    |    true   |  1  |
|3  |    1    |    true   |  2  |
|4  |    2    |   false   |  2  |
|5  |    3    |    true   |  3  |
|6  |    5    |   false   |  4  |
|7  |    5    |   false   |  4  |
|8  |    5    |    true   |  4  |
|9  |    5    |   false   |  4  |
```

**Task**:
Fetch all subitems `levels` <= 3 in the folder `id == 1`.
The result ids should be [1,3,5]

My current implementation is recursively queries, which means, for the example above, my program would fetch id == 1 first and then find all items with `is_categorh == true` and `level` <= 3.

It doesn't feel like a efficient way.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Efficient in what way? Conciseness of programming, resource usage in the server, programming of the app, debugging, error-free app? I think a recursive query is pretty efficient if you have the right indexes.

Comment: @TheImpaler I am guessing he means repeatedly querying to get the children, not a recursive CTE.

Comment: @JsW . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are using and the version.  The solution probably requires recursive CTEs and not all versions of all databases support them.

Comment: If this exists as a table, with pre-identified links, and attributes of `is_category` and `level`, then you have no need to go recursive. A `WHERE` clause that states `is_category == true and level <= 3` could be executed on this table. If this is instead the result of a recursive CTE on a table that just has things like `file_id`, `parent_id` and other file metadata, then you are correct that filtering by the computed values of `is_category` and `level` would be inefficient since they are non-deterministic values that couldn't be leveraged by an optimizer efficiently.

Comment: @Uueerdo I read the question again and you are right. I automatically assumed the OP was talking about recursive CTEs, but I guess he was not.

Comment: @TheImpaler Sorry for the unclear.  I mean the resource usage in the server. Thought recursive query is not efficient.

Comment: @Solonotix A WHERE clause that states is_category == true and level <= 3 will return all folders has level <= 3 including those not in the folder we specified. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @JsW, my apologies. I didn't realize you were asking for all children of id == 1, which is clearly stated in your question. As long as your base table has something like a Primary Key on the Id column, and another Index on the ParentId column, it should be a fairly efficient operation. Note that all recursive solutions run the possibility of exponential complexity, which would make a typically fast method take forever to run. See any node_modules folder for an example of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention the database you are using so I'll assume PostgreSQL.

You can retrieve the rows you want using a single query that uses a "Recursive CTE". Recursive CTEs are implemented by several database engines, such as Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MariaDB, MySQL, HyperSQL, H2, Teradata, etc.

The query should take a for similar to:

```
with recursive x as (
  select * from t where id = 1
  union all
  select t.*
  from x
  join t on t.parent_id = x.id and t.level <= 3
)
select id from x
```

For the record, the data script I used to test it is:

```
create table t (
  id int,
  parent_id int,
  level int
);

insert into t (id, parent_id, level) values (0, -1, 0);
insert into t (id, parent_id, level) values (1, 0, 1);
insert into t (id, parent_id, level) values (2, 0, 1);
insert into t (id, parent_id, level) values (3, 1, 2);
insert into t (id, parent_id, level) values (4, 2, 2);
insert into t (id, parent_id, level) values (5, 3, 3);
insert into t (id, parent_id, level) values (6, 5, 4);
insert into t (id, parent_id, level) values (7, 5, 4);
insert into t (id, parent_id, level) values (8, 5, 4);
insert into t (id, parent_id, level) values (9, 5, 4);
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because 1) you provided a mostly ANSI-SQL code sample and 2) you provided code to generate the data you tested with. I however feel you missed the question which was "I'm doing this recursively, but is it the most efficient way?" This question could probably be closed as opinion or too broad, but I leave that up to others to determine.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, recursive CTE's are a fast, and typically efficient method to retrieve the data you're looking for. If you wanted to avoid recursive CTE's, since they aren't infinitely scalable, and thus prone to erratic behavior given certain use cases, you could also take a more direct approach by implementing the recursive search via a `WHILE` loop. Note that this is not more efficient than the recursive CTE, but it is something that gives you more control over what happens in the recursion. In my sample, I am using Transact-SQL.

First, setup code, like @The Impaler provided:

```
drop table if exists
    dbo.folder_tree;

create table dbo.folder_tree 
    (
    id int not null constraint [PK_folder_tree] primary key clustered,
    parent_id int not null,
    fs_level int not null,
    is_category bit not null constraint [DF_folder_tree_is_category] default(0),
    constraint [UQ_folder_tree_parent_id] unique(parent_id, id)
    );

insert into dbo.folder_tree 
    (id, parent_id, fs_level, is_category)
values 
    (0, -1, 0, 1),  --|0  |   -1    |    true   |  0  |
    (1, 0, 1, 1),   --|1  |    0    |    true   |  1  |
    (2, 0, 1, 1),   --|2  |    0    |    true   |  1  |
    (3, 1, 2, 1),   --|3  |    1    |    true   |  2  |
    (4, 2, 2, 0),   --|4  |    2    |   false   |  2  |
    (5, 3, 3, 1),   --|5  |    3    |    true   |  3  |
    (6, 5, 4, 0),   --|6  |    5    |   false   |  4  |
    (7, 5, 4, 0),   --|7  |    5    |   false   |  4  |
    (8, 5, 4, 1),   --|8  |    5    |    true   |  4  |
    (9, 5, 4, 0);   --|9  |    5    |   false   |  4  |
```

And then the code for implementing a recursive search of the table via `WHILE` loop:

```
drop function if exists
    dbo.folder_traverse;
go

create function dbo.folder_traverse
    (
    @start_id int,
    @max_level int = null
    )
returns @result table
    (
    id int not null primary key,
    parent_id int not null,
    fs_level int not null,
    is_category bit not null
    )
as
    begin
        insert into 
            @result
        select
            id,
            parent_id,
            fs_level,
            is_category
        from
            dbo.folder_tree
        where
            id = @start_id;

        while @@ROWCOUNT > 0
            begin
                insert into 
                    @result
                select
                    f.id,
                    f.parent_id,
                    f.fs_level,
                    f.is_category
                from
                    @result r
                    inner join dbo.folder_tree f on
                        r.id = f.parent_id
                where
                    f.is_category = 1 and
                    (
                        @max_level is null or
                        f.fs_level <= @max_level
                    )
                    except
                select
                    id,
                    parent_id,
                    fs_level,
                    is_category
                from
                    @result;
            end;

        return;
    end;
go
```

In closing, the only reason I'd recommend this approach is if you have a large number of recursive members, or need to add logging or some other process in between actions. This approach is slower in most use cases, and adds complexity to the code, but is an alternative to the recursive CTE and meets your required criteria.